# Android get json from http request raising IOException: Attempted read on closed stream

Tags: java, android, json

Trying to get the json from http request by using this class:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

      }
          }
```

But some times getting the exception like

**E/Buffer Error(300): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on          closed stream.**

Can any one help on this thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste your log cat error.

Comment: Why do you have a *static* InputStream field? Having an InputStream field of any kind is unusual... making it static is almost *certainly* inappropriate. All of your static variables would probably be better as local variables.

Comment: Are you definitively sure that the input is iso-8859-1?

Comment: @jon Skeet thanks i think you are absolutely right.But why its getting exception ,Actually i was calling this method from Async class multiple times in getview of the pageviewer .

Comment: @etienne, i was not sure about iso-8859-1 can you suggest the standard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this way..

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Perform a GET request for a JSON list
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("https://somejson.json");
        // Get the response that sends back
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks i changed the code to this:Now its double faster than before.

But i need to test more number of times since i was getting the exception which i posted as question very rarely.

```
   public class JSONParser {

InputStream is = null;
JSONObject jObj = null;
String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Perform a GET request for a JSON list
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
    // Get the response that sends back
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    try {
        json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
    }
```

It was faster than before ,But problem is app crashing when its the network connection is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the static. With me it worked after the removal.

**static** InputStream is = null;

Answer (score -1):

At first i really don't like your static `InputStream` variable, why static? Just make it normal variable and not static. And especially in Android static variables are not a win at all.

And second if you want to get `JSON` from Server you need to use `GET` request instead of `POST`

**And to question.**

I think problem is that you should close `BufferedReader` rather than `InputStream`

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
reader.close();
// next work
```

And at the end one suggestion. What about to use [`EntityUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) instead of **getContent()**. You will save a time by it instead of reading from InputStream.

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

and now you have quickly `JSON` as String.

Answer (score -2):

just make `InputStream`  `non-static` that's all.
I used post method and just fine...